# Is there a way to view raw data in Firebase A/B testing?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-ab-testing

I am using Google Firebase for A/B testing, and in the past I have been able to view and export aggregate data directly from Firebase. I can even set up funnels and audiences and then export the data from the Firebase console.

It does not seem like there is any way to view data based on 'Variant A' and 'Variant B'. Is there a way to view the data, parsed by A/B variant assignment?

Comment: Do you mean to split by variant in Firebase console or in BigQuery?

Comment: I was able to replicate this .. there should be a View in BigQuery optin in context menu. https://firebase.google.com/docs/ab-testing/abtest-config#bigquery_data_export Please file a bug in Firebase Support.